# Grafana alert icon not showing up on side bar with viewer role

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

When a user has a viewer role, shouldn't that user be able to view the alerts list.  I wouldn't expect the user to be able to edit anything there, but there should be view permissions right?  I'm currently using 7.2.1 and when a user has a view role they are not able to see the alert icon on the left hand side of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is the expected behavior for viewer role.

For someone to be able to view alerts you need at least an editor role.

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/permissions/organization_roles/